# Problem with install pentium-builder

Tags: software-installation

I want to install Pentium-builder but when i press this command the terminal shows this message

```
Reading package list.. Done  Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Pentium-builder
```

What should I do with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the package is `pentium-builder` and not `Pentium-builder`. Linux is case-sensitive. But that's not the problem. The package system is smart enough to know, what you mean (at least in Wily). But you have to enable the universe repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pentium-builder
```

And you're using Saucy, a End-of-Life release

```
sudo sed -i 's/us\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pentium-builder
```

Comment: after install repository universe the terminal shows 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all source, but after getting update the terminal shows E: some index file failed to download. they have been ignored, or old ones used instead. so when i install pentium-builder it shows last error

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install pastebinit; sudo apt-get update | pastebinit`. Give me the link, but be patient, the command will take some time.

Comment: when i type sudo apt-get install pastebinit again it shows Reading packagr list ... Done   Building dependency tree   Reading state information ... Done    E: Unable to lacate packeage pastebinit

Comment: Ok, run `sudo apt-get update` and add the output manually here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/13513430/

Comment: You're using Saucy, a End-of-Life release. `sudo sed -i 's/us\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: My problem got fixed. Thank you for the guidance.